# Run Patch once: Installehield Project

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, patch

I have created a patch that runs successfully, however I only wish to make it install once and therefore not allow say a v1.1 to be installed twice.

My understanding is I can use install conditions to do this however I have tried some of the combinations using Install conditions such as: Installed  , Not installed etc and I have not seemed to get anywhere. Sorry if this seems a silly question I just feel like I may be missing the point.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do check this site for the answer.

http://installjournal.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-do-you-check-whether-patch-is.html